# JSONKit with Key-Value Coding and BOOLs

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding, jsonkit

I'm attempting to serialize various objects by using Key-Value Coding to convert them to an NSDictionary, then JSONKit to serialize the NSDictionary to an NSString/NSData.  I'm running into problems converting BOOL properties.

The [KVC guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html) state that `valueForKey:` will, for BOOL properties, create an NSNumber via `[NSNumber numberWithBool:]`.  JSONKit [states that](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) NSNumbers created via `numberWithBool:` will be serialized to true/false.  I've tested JSONKit's claim and it works.  However, when I access a BOOL value with KVC, I get an object which does not look like it was created via `numberWithBool:`.  In particular, it does not evaluate equal to kCFBooleanTrue, which JSONKit uses as a marker for a boolean.  The end result is that my BOOL properties are serialized to 0/1 instead of true/false, which is causing problems for the receiving API.

How do I determine if an NSNumber from KVC came from a BOOL property?  Am I misreading Apple's documentation?  Or is there some other way to get this serialization procedure to work?

Below is the test which is failing:

```
#import "JSONKit.h"

- (void) testCompareKVCBoolToNumberWithBool {
    NSNumber *numberBool = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    //This passes
    STAssertTrue(numberBool == (id)kCFBooleanTrue, @"Number %@ should kCFBooleanTrue.", numberBool);

    TestModel *model = [[TestModel alloc] init];
    model.boolProperty = YES;
    NSNumber *kvcBool = [model valueForKey:@"boolProperty"];
    //This fails
    STAssertTrue(kvcBool == (id)kCFBooleanTrue, @"Number %@ should be a kCFBooleanTrue.", kvcBool);

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      numberBool, @"numberBool",
                      kvcBool, @"kvcBool",
                      nil];
    NSString *jsonString = [dict JSONString];
    //This yields: jsonString: {"kvcBool":1,"numberBool":true}
    NSLog(@"jsonString: %@", jsonString);
}
```

And here is the TestModel code:

```
@interface TestModel : NSObject 
@property (assign)          BOOL            boolProperty;
@end

@implementation TestModel
@synthesize boolProperty = _boolProperty;
@end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout my implementation which does this automatically - https://github.com/QBurst/KVCObjectSerializer

Comment: This has the same problem that my implementation has, which is that a `BOOL` is converted into `0` or `1`, not `true` or `false`.  Check out https://gist.github.com/3762811 for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Will look into the issue and your implementation. :)